# loading data from Firebase returns null only for the first time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing two values into firebase database as shown below

```
    String key = mClientDatabaseReference.push().getKey();

                   // get user input and set it to result
                   // edit text
                   Client client = new Client( firstNameEditText.getText().toString(), lastNameEditText.getText().toString() );
                   mClientDatabaseReference.child( key ).child( "firstName" ).setValue( firstNameEditText.getText().toString() );
                   mClientDatabaseReference.child( key ).child( "lastName" ).setValue( lastNameEditText.getText().toString() );
```

and everything is working fine except for a tiny annoying thing that is happening with the ChildEventListener. when the onChildAdded is called it is called after setting the value of the first name and it doesn't wait until the second name value is being sat, so I get only the first name with the second name being null and I have to reopen the activity to get the full firs and last name.
this is the code in onChildAdded

```
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Client client = dataSnapshot.getValue( Client.class );
            mClientAdapter.add( client );           
            Log.d(TAG+"Added",dataSnapshot.getValue(Client.class).toString());
        }
```

how can I get over this problem?

Comment: but how may I do that it is a inside a listener and it is updated each time a value is added...is there away to add these values in one line in a way?

Comment: can you show the code `onchildadded`?

Comment: The answer gave me the idea of putting a value listener in the on child added and catching children whose value had been rendered null by the setValue() updates to it. It works. Doesn't make sense to me why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use addvalueeventlistener:

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String name=datas.child("firstName").getValue().toString();
   String lname=datas.child("lastName").getValue().toString();
  }
}
    @Override 
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
 });
```

since you want to retrieve data only, then use addvalueeventlistener or addListenerForSingleValueEvent if you want to read once. Assuming you have the following database:

```
users
 userid
    firstName:firstname
    lastName: lastname
```

Comment: not yet, I'm trying something out if it didn't work I'll try this...thanks again though